# read values in a file and convert them according to their type in python

Tags: python, input, type-conversion

I have the following file:

```
 10                 10                  11                  10530           18              100             0               Open    ;
 11                 11                  12                  5280            14              100             0               Open    ;
 12                 12                  13                  5280            10              100             0               Open    ;
 21                 21                  22                  5280            10              100             0               Open    ;
```

I read the file as follow:

```
 with open(file) as f:
 values = line.rstrip().split()
```

this is the outcome for the first line:

```
values
Out  [2]: ['10', '10', '11', '10530', '18', '100', '0', 'Open']
```

I would like to convert some of them to integer, float or keep them as string.

The easiest way could be the following:

```
values[0]  = int(values[0])
values[1]  = int(values[1])
values[2]  = int(values[2])
values[3]  = float(values[3])
values[4]  = float(values[4])
values[5]  = float(values[5])
values[6]  = float(values[6])
values[7]  = values[7]
```

Do you have in mind other more compact or smarter way to do that?

I could for example write the values that I want to convert to float as float in the file by adding a dot. For example, 2 as 2.0.
However, I am stuck again with the conversion.

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: "write the values that I want to convert to float as float in the file", what do you mean by this?  Are you in charge of the format, or you're limited to only parsing it? Are the column types fixed, or do yo have to handle different types?

Comment: Instead of implementing your own parser why not let `pandas` do the work?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for might be something like this:

```py
values[0:2] = [int(values[i]) for i in range(3)]
values[3:6] = [float(values[i]) for i in range(3, 7)]
```

This should save you duplicating your code lines although it isn't the best practice to do it.
If you're into learning a better way to do this kind of file parsing I would recommend you to learn how to use [pandas](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/pandas_intro.asp)